# Why was King David allowed to mourn on the floor?

Tags: mourning-aveilus, malchut-royalty, samuel-shmuel-book-of, king-david

I heard from my rav that one of the laws of a king is that during mourning, he is not allowed to sit on the floor. Rather he sits on a couch, so as not shame his status as the king.

If this is true, how was King David allowed to mourn on the floor as we see in Shmuel II 12:16?

Comment: That's from the Mishna: Sanhedrin paragraph 2 Mishna 3. As general guideline, trying to resolve conflicts of that kind (biblical figure does not follow Halacha that is written later on), not always gets reasonable results.

Comment: Is that deoraisa?  99+% of derabbanans didn't exist yet.

Answer (score 3):

He's not mourning. Heis praying that the child should survive; indeed when it does die he no longer weeps or fasts,much to his servants consternation https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.12.21?with=all&lang=bi

Comment: That's an excellent point that I guess I missed. I have to recheck the chronology.